# How to get python to recognize the next occurrence of letter in hangman

Tags: python, python-2.7

My hangman program is fully functioning except there is one problem, let's say the word is mathematics, I guess `m`, `a`, `t`, `h`, `e` - but once I guess the other `m`, it says I guessed it (as opposed to saying "You already guessed this letter") but it doesn't replace the `_`.

My Code:

```
def start():
    import random
    words = ["barbershop", "cuddle", "furious", "demolition", "centaur", "forest", "pineapple", "mathematics", "turkish"]
    word = random.choice(words);
    hiddenword = len(word) * "-"
    used_letters = []
    lives = 6
    print "Welcome to Hangman! You have 6 guesses, good luck!"

    while True:
        print word
        print "".join(hiddenword)
        guess = raw_input("> ")
        hiddenword = list(hiddenword)

    if len(guess) > 1:
        print "Error: 1 Letter Maximum"
    elif len(guess) < 1:
        guess = raw_input("> ")
    else:
        if guess.isdigit() == True:
            print "Error: Hangman only accepts letters."
        else:
            if guess in used_letters and word.count(guess) == 1:
                print "You already guessed that letter"
            else:
                if guess.lower() in word:
                    print "You got the letter " + "'" + guess + "'" + "!"
                    hiddenword[word.index(guess)] = guess
                    used_letters.append(guess)
                else:
                    lives -= 1
                    print "-1 Guesses"
                    print "Guesses:", lives
                    used_letters.append(guess)

    if lives == 0:
        print "GAME OVER: You're out of guesses, try again!"
        break
    if hiddenword == word:
        print "Cangratulations, you got the word!"
        break

start()
```

P.S. - I know I have a lot of excess code e.g. `if` statements, please do not comment on that.

Comment: What should happen when you guess first `m`? Should the first instance of `m` be revealed or all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be with the line:

`hiddenword[word.index(guess)] = guess`

The string method `.index(x)` returns the index of the *first* incidence of `x`. So this line will persistently fill in the first "m" in mathematics.

Assuming you want the game to reveal *all* instances of a letter when it is guessed (e.g., show both m's in "mathematics" when you guess "m"), you can substitute this:

```
for i, x in enumerate(word):
    if word[i] == guess:
        hiddenword[i] = guess
```

for your line:

```
hiddenword[word.index(guess)] = guess
```

Also, to get the "Congratulations!" message to appear, you will need to change `if hiddenword == word` to `if ''.join(hiddenword) == word`, since `hiddenword` is a list at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Removing multiple occurences of a character in a string in python is easily achieved using:

```
your_string.replace("m", "");
```

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm